# RVM Gemset - Bundler & Capistrano in Production

Tags: rvm, capistrano

I'm deploying a rails app to a VPS with capistrano, bundler and rvm. 
Here is part of my deploy.rb

```
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))
require "rvm/capistrano"     
require "bundler/capistrano"             # Load RVM's capistrano plugin.

set :rvm_type, :system
set :rvm_ruby_string, '1.9.2@gemset_name'
```

my .rvmrc

```
rvm --create use 1.9.2@gemset_name
```

When I logged into the server I noticed that the rvm gemset was created, however all the gems were installed in /shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems --not in the gemset(/usr/local/rvm/gemset)

I use RVM in development and I think it's great but when is time to deploy to production. what are the best practices? Is there a way to tell bundler to install the gems in the gemset?

Do I even need a gemset at all? (seems like bundler is already isolating gemsets), Am I missing something?

Please help me understand!

Thank you very much

Answer (score 17):

I use RVM in development and production as well. However, while I use gemsets in development to separate gems between my rails projects, I only use RVM to install rubies on my production VPS and let Bundler handle the versions of my gems.

Using the bundler integration via `require "bundler/capistrano"` automatically sets some things up for bundler. You can see the code behind this in [Bundlers Github page](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/deployment.rb). The basic settings are so that bundle executes this command:

```
bundle install --gemfile Gemfile --path shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test
```

As you can see, the `--deployment` and `--path` flags are given, which tells Bundler to bundle your gems with your application in the `shared/bundle` directory, and only use the versions specified in your Gemfile.lock (i.e. the versions that are working in development). Since the bundle directory is shared between deployments, I find it comparable to using RVM gemsets for each application, just easier.

If you still want to put gems in separate gemsets I'd recommend [this tutorial from Darcy Laycock](http://blog.ninjahideout.com/posts/the-path-to-better-rvm-and-passenger-integration) for further reading.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I am letting bundler handle the gems for each one of my projects and it is working great so far.

Comment: +1 on RVM in development, bundler in production. I'm using this method to run multiple ruby apps on the one host, no issues yet.