# rails, new ubuntu install, capistrano, rvm issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, capistrano

I'm a new user to Capistrano and using it to deploy a rails 3.1 app. There seems to be an issue with gem installation on the remote server.

I have the following questions:

1. It looks like cap runs bundle install on the `gemfile`? Are there any dependencies for this to work successfully? I have `rvm` and `bundler` on my server. Does it need rails installed already?
2. I have manually set the `bundle_cmd` in my `deploy.rb` like this:

   ```
   set :bundle_cmd, '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/bundle'
   ```

   Should this be correct?
3. Is there a way to have confirmation on a cap deploy that ALL the required gems are there? Or what is the best way to debug a failed bundle install on the remote server? Can you call something like `cap gem-list`; was hoping something like `cap invoke=gem list` would do it but doesn't look like it.

**Edit #1**

I'm getting the following error:
failed: "rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'default' -c 'cd /data/sites/myserver/apps/myapp/releases/20111204181321 && bundle install --gemfile /data/sites/myserver/apps/myapp/releases/20111204181321/Gemfile --path /data/sites/myserver/apps/myapp/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test'" on 173.230.xxx.xxx

If I go into a previous release, and run bundle install, it says that everything installed correctly which it didn't.

It says:

```
Your bundle is complete! It was installed into /data/sites/myserver/apps/myapp/shared/bundle
```

but if I go in there, there is nothing other than the ruby 1.9.1 which to the best of my knowledge I didn't install (using ruby 1.9.2-p290)

Is there a way in capistrono to specify it not to delete the deployed release so that I can debug that explicitly? Shoud I need to hardcode the path to my bundler in my deploy.rb script?

thx again

**EDIT 2**
If I go into the current release at:

```
/data/sites/myserver/apps/myapp/current
```

and run:

```
$ which bundle
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin//bundle
```

I get:

```
$ bundle install
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [minitest-1.6.0,rake-0.8.7, rdoc-2.5.8] (Gem::LoadError)
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1210:in `gem'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/bundle:18:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you try `cap shell` (local) and then run `rvm current` and `which bundle` in the capistrano shell? The Capistrano shell gives you an opportunity to work from the environment as cap sees it.

Answer (score 1):

1. You dont need to have rails installed already, but I do think that you need to have bundler installed. `gem install bundler`
2. You can use RVM and bundler integration from capistrano. In that case you dont have to set the path to bundler.

   ```
   $:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))
   require "rvm/capistrano"     
   require "bundler/capistrano"     # Load RVM's capistrano plugin.

   set :rvm_type, :system
   set :rvm_ruby_string, '1.9.2@gemset_name'
   ```
3. You can use 'cap shell' to run commands through Capistrano on the server. You could use this to check the installation of all your gems. Use `cap -T` to see all possibilities.

On a side note, do you really need rvm gemsets for your app? I use RVM to install and update my rubies on my production server, but I let Bundler handle the separation of my gems. Since the default bundler settings in production put all your gems in vendor/bundle, this already separates your gems from each other. This works great with Capistrano too.

See a similar question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7930228/980210). Some more information a capistrano/bundler/rvm/passenger setup can be find in [this tutorial](http://web-l.nl/posts/5-setting-up-a-rails-production-server-part-1).