# bundler/capistrano is not installing gems with correct ruby version

Tags: rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rvm, capistrano

I'm trying to deploy my first app on a server with Capistrano, and I'm a bit **lost with managing gemsets and ruby version**.

These are my (server and workstation) versions :

- Rails 3.2.8
- RVM 1.16.17
- Gem 1.8.24
- Bundler 1.2.1
- pg gem 0.14.1

My gemset are :

Gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p194 (found in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194)

- (default)
- global
- => rail3dev20120606

I set the default gemset with :

```
rvm use 1.9.3-p194@rail3dev20120606 --default --passenger
```

When I run a :

```
cap bundle:install
```

The task end with success, but when I do a :

```
gem list
```

There are many **missing gems** though they are present in my Gemfile.
When I go to check my gems in **/var/www/opf/shared/bundle/ruby/** I find a folder called **1.9.1** and in /var/www/opf/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ I can fond all of my needed gems (specified in Gemfile). I'm sure there is a problem with ruby version, but how do I solve this ?

At the moment, if I do any rake command, I got a ruby crash [Bug] Segmentation fault, as it try to access the db and using postgresql_adapter :

```
/var/www/opf/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1213: [BUG] Segmentation fault
```

I think as many gems are missing there must have some gem dependencies not verified, and maybe a gem is using an incompatible ruby version 1.9.1 though it expect a 1.9.3.

I think the issue is around managing ruby versions and gems. I'm certainly doing some mix with gemset and my capistrano deployement.

I'm missing experience and info.
Could anybody advise me how to handle this on the server ? What are the best practices ?

**How am I suppose to update my ruby version ? with Capistrano deploy.rb ? manually ? with/without rvm ? I saw a new version of ruby 1.9.3-p327 has just released.**

**Should I use gemset or not ? What about the :rvm_ruby_string in my deploy.rb. Is it correctly spelled or should I remove the p194 part ? Should I Remove the :rvm_ruby_string ? Keep it ? Use a .rvmrc file ???**

**I'm really lost and some kind help would be welcome.**

This is my config/deploy.rb in any case :

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'deploy') + '/capistrano_database'

set :rvm_type, :system

set :rvm_ruby_string, 'ruby-1.9.3-p194@rail3dev20120606'
require 'rvm/capistrano'

set :application, 'opf'
set :deploy_to, '/var/www/opf'
set :rails_env, 'production'
set :user, 'the_user'
set :use_sudo, false

set :group_writable, false
set :scm, :git
set :repository,  'git@github.com:user/opf.git'
set :branch, 'master'

default_run_options[:pty] = true

set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

server '192.168.5.200', :web, :app, :db, :primary => true

# If you are using Passenger mod_rails uncomment this:
namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628763/rvm-gemset-bundler-capistrano-in-production) helped me to understand the two possiblities to manage gem :

- [To put gems within the app folder](http://web-l.nl/posts/5-setting-up-a-rails-production-server-part-1)
- [To put gems in separate gemsets](http://blog.ninjahideout.com/posts/the-path-to-better-rvm-and-passenger-integration)

Answer (score 4):

the gems are installed, but they are installed with a context of bundler:

```
bundle exec gem list
```

this is because bundler stored it's settings in `.bundle/config` and did not installed shared gems, instead all gems are installed in per project separate directory, treat it as a inplace gemset.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any idea why I got this error then : /var/www/opf/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1213: [BUG] Segmentation fault. And why the folder is called ruby/1.9.1. Is it ruby 1.9.1 that is used instead of 1.9.3 ?

Comment: 1.9.1 is a compatibility level of all 1.9.x rubies, as for the `BUG` -  it's a new question

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your first answer. How do I use my gemsets ? I don't want gems to be saved in my app folder. This doesn't make sens since gemset are there to manage gems.

Comment: you are using `require 'bundler/capistrano'` refer to http://gembundler.com for configuration of where gems are installed.